# class Diagram for nodejs and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hei everyone, Please I need some help,

I have started a project which will use NodeJS and mongoDB , and I'm new to these technologies,

my problem is that I need to analyse my subject,and I wonder if the class diagram will be useful ? 
and can we develop interfaces and classes that implement them using Nodejs?

I'm lost , i don't know how should I make the classe diagram to work with Nodejs and mongo.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Javascript does not have interfaces, just classes. Javascript classes are just like classes in any other language, so your class diagrams would be the same, but the format of your code would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example [here](https://github.com/vedovelli/screencast-restful) is the best to learn nodejs + mongo, to analyse the subject I suggest the website [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/), I guess the class diagram will help you a lot with the struture of your DB.

Comment: thank you so much, i'm already using draw.io and it's just amazing .. thank youu :D